# What does it mean by DN in salt-pepper noise?

Tags: image-processing, noise

What is DN on [page 245 of these notes](http://www2.engr.arizona.edu/~dial/ece533/notes12.pdf) shown in the slide below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same course, you can find the following indication in an [earlier set of slides](http://www2.engr.arizona.edu/~dial/ece533/notes7.pdf):

> Input quantized image pixel values (integers): Digital Number (DN)

From this you can infer that

> Salt noise: DN = maximum possible

indicates that salt noise shows up as pixels with the largest possible pixel values (e.g. 255 if the picture is a grey scale picture represented by pixel in the `[0-255]` range), and that

> Pepper noise: DN = minimum possible

indicates that pepper noise shows up as pixels with the smallest possible pixel values (e.g. 0 if the picture is a grey scale picture represented by pixel in the `[0-255]` range).